# Redis Lua decoding Json returning empty table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to run a lua script in my Redis instance from nodejs. I set a json object `{one:1, two:'2', three: {four: 4}}` in my cache then run the following script in lua:

```
local value = redis.call('get', 'myKey')
local obj = cjson.decode(value)
return obj
```

The result that returns to node is `[]`

I tried to return the type with the line: `return type(obj)` and it comes back as a table. Calling `return type(value)` gives me `string`. Why is cjson not decoding the actual object? Is there something else I can use to decode my string to json.

Comment: Make sure the quotes are correct (double; and also around the keys) and JSON valid in your cache.

Comment: The retrieval of ```value``` from redis.call is working. I'm getting the json value ```{"one":1,"two":"2","three":{"four":4}}``` back in node. It is coming through as a json object. The problem is I need to perform some expensive operations within the redis enviornment, and the type of the ```value``` variable in redis is string. I think its getting serialzed by the redis api when the value returns, but the fact that cjson isn't working is making me think otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located the problem. It doesn't look like node is serializing a decoded lua json object, it only returns an empty array `[]`. It is decoding in lua though. The following code returns a json object in node:

```
local value = redis.call("get", "myKey")
local obj = cjson.decode(value)
return cjson.encode(obj)
```

In addition the following code is returning `1`

```
local value = redis.call("get", "myKey")
local obj = cjson.decode(value)
return obj.one
```

So the json object is being created, I think the json serializer in the redis package is looking for a string from lua.

Comment: Somehow arrays with scalars work correctly: `return {'A', 'B'}` = `['A', 'B']` but not nested objects `return {'A', { tag: 'hot'}}` will be empty arrays `['A', []]` ; this post was the only thing i found in that regard, thus still unclear why.